# Python: ' ' is not defined

Tags: python, nameerror

Here is my code:

```
# This program makes the robot calculate the average amount of light in a simulated room

from myro import *
init("simulator")

from random import*

def pressC():
    """ Wait for "c" to be entered from the keyboard in the Python shell """
    entry = " "
    while(entry != "c"):
        entry = raw_input("Press c to continue. ")
    print("Thank you. ")
    print

def randomPosition():
    """ This gets the robot to drive to a random position """
    result = randint(1, 2)
    if(result == 1):
        forward(random(), random())
    if(result == 2):
        backward(random(), random())

def scan():
    """ This allows the robot to rotate and print the numbers that each light sensors obtains """
    leftLightSeries = [0,0,0,0,0,0]
    centerLightSeries = [0,0,0,0,0,0]
    rightLightSeries = [0,0,0,0,0,0]
    for index in range(1,6):
        leftLight = getLight("left")
        leftLightSeries[index] = leftLightSeries[index] + leftLight
        centerLight = getLight("center")
        centerLightSeries[index] = centerLightSeries[index] + centerLight
        rightLight = getLight("right")
        rightLightSeries[index] = rightLightSeries[index] + rightLight
        turnRight(.5,2.739)
    return leftLightSeries
    return centerLightSeries
    return rightLightSeries

def printResults():
    """ This function prints the results of the dice roll simulation."""
    print " Average Light Levels "
    print "    L      C      R "
    print "========================="
    for index in range(1, 6):
        print str(index) + " " + str(leftLightSeries[index]) + " " + str(centerLightSeries[index]) + " " + str(rightLightSeries[index])

def main():
    senses()
    pressC()
    randomPosition()
    scan() 
    printResults()

main()
```

So, I am getting this error when I run my program.

```
NameError: global name 'leftLightSeries' is not defined
```

I understand that I must be doing something wrong related to the return statement. I'm not sure if I can only return one variable at the end of a user-defined function. If that were to be true, then I should probably separate the scan(): function. Anyways, I would appreciate any help on how to fix this error. Also, this is the result that I am looking for when I successfully complete my program:
[Click Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zgHOU.png)

I am looking to complete the average values like the picture shows, but I am not worried about them at this point, only the list of values from the light sensors. I do not need to reach those exact numbers, the numbers will vary in the simulator.

Comment: `leftLightSeries` is a local variable within your `scan()` function, and exists only there. therefore it's not available for use in `printResults()`. and multiple sequential `return` calls like that don't make sense in any language. `return` sends execution control back to the original calling place immediately. any lines of code after a `return` never get executed.

Comment: You're not using the return value from scan(). However if you did want to return three values from a function, you can return them as a tuple e.g. `return (leftLightSeries, centerLightSeries, rightLightSeries)`.

Comment: Only the first `return` statement will be executed (`return leftLightSeries`). If you want to return multiple values, use a dictionary, tuple, set or list.

Comment: I returned all three, but I am still getting the nameerror

Comment: Doesn't python give you a Traceback of the calls leading up to the exception? Edit your question to include the entire traceback; this often gives important clues as to where the exception is happening. Others have guessed that the error might be in the printResults() function, which is credible given that there is neither a local variable nor a global named leftLightSeries within the scope of that function. Function printResults() needs to be supplied with parameters (leftLightSeries, etc.) so that it can know what to report. See python docs section 7.6 Function definitions parameter list.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return multiple items from `scan()`, don't use three separate `return` statements.  Instead, do this:

```
return leftLightSeries, centerLightSeries, rightLightSeries
```

Also, when you call the function, you have to assign variable(s) to the returned values; it won't automatically create new local variables with the same names.  So in `main`, call `scan()` like this:

```
leftLightSeries, centerLightSeries, rightLightSeries = scan()
```

Comment: I am still getting the name error after doing that for some reason